# Print text after every ! (exclamation mark) in bash

Tags: bash, printing, delimiter, cut

I would like print strings/texts after every `!` (exclamation mark) in bash.

Example string/text:

```
check_queue!TEST_IN!Queue!400!750
```

I want this output:

```
TEST_IN Queue 400 750
```

I have tried this:

```
cat filename | cut -d "!" -f2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there:

```sh
cut -d! -f2- filename | tr '!' ' '
```

`-f2-` means field 2 and all following fields

No need for `cat`, just work on file

`tr '!' ' '` translates exclamation mark `!` to space  .

Or if your version of `cut` has an `--output-delimiter=` option:

```sh
cut --delimiter=! --fields=2- --output-delimiter=' ' filename
```

Or using `awk`:

```sh
awk -F! '{$1=""; print substr($0,2)}' filename
```

- `-F!`: Sets the field delimiter to `!`
- `$1=""`: Erase first field
- `print substr($0,2)`: Print the whole record starting at 2nd character, since first one is blank delimiter remain from erased first field.

Answer (score 0):

Fist apply a FOREACH line loop

```
while read s; do
  #foreach substring 
    for (( i=0; i<${#s}; i++ )); do
if ["${s:$i:1}" != “!”] then
   #add to the String the extra letter 
   String="${s} ${s:$i:1}"
else
    #print each time you find !
    print String 
    #prepare it to print next String
    String =“”
fi 
done
  done <your filename.txt
```